# Why is colgroup width percentage ignored when some columns are hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and columns 2 through 7 are hidden, while others have a width percentage assigned via the `colgroup` method.  For whatever reason, the `width` percentage is ignored.  However, if I "unhide" columns 2-7, the percentage is taken into account.

How do I force the browser to respect the width with columns 2-7 hidden?

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget-comparables-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(2),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(3),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(4),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(5),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(6),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(7) {
  display: none;
}


.widget-comparable-col-prop-summary {
  width: 59%;
}

.widget-comparable-col-prop-sales {
  width: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; background-color:green">
  <table class="widget-comparables-table">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-address" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sold-price" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sold-date" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-beds" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-baths" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sqft" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-prop-summary" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-prop-sales" />
    </colgroup>

    <tr class="widget-comparables-main-property-row">
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
      <td>col5</td>
      <td>col6</td>
      <td>col7</td>
      <td>col8</td>
      <td>col9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it changing:

```
.widget-comparable-col-prop-summary {
  width: 59%;
}
.widget-comparable-col-prop-sales {
  width: 39%;
}
```

with:

```
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(8) {
  width: 59%;
}
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(9) {
  width: 39%;
}
```

I'm not familiar with [`colgroup`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp) tag, so I cannot give you a deep explanation. But in [w3schools HTML < colgroup > width Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colgroup_width.asp) I saw these Compatibility Notes:

> The width attribute of < colgroup > is not supported in HTML5.
>
> Use CSS instead. CSS syntax: < td style="width:200px" >

The snippet:

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget-comparables-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(2),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(3),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(4),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(5),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(6),
.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(7) {
  display: none;
}


.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(8) {
  width: 59%;
}

.widget-comparables-table tr > *:nth-child(9) {
  width: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; background-color:green">
  <table class="widget-comparables-table">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-address" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sold-price" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sold-date" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-beds" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-baths" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-sqft" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-prop-summary" />
      <col class="widget-comparable-col-prop-sales" />
    </colgroup>

    <tr class="widget-comparables-main-property-row">
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
      <td>col5</td>
      <td>col6</td>
      <td>col7</td>
      <td>col8</td>
      <td>col9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```